# Select tag helper - unexpected behavior when controller argument name matches model property

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I ran into an issue with the default value of a `<select>` element not being properly set to the value of the property model I set it to in the tag helper.

My original code that led to the issue:

Controller Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test(int? id = null, string siteAbbreviation = null)
{
    MyModel model = await GetModelData(id, siteAbbreviation);

    model.SiteAbbreviation = "AA";

    return PartialView("Test", model);
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel
<select asp-for="SiteAbbreviation" class="form-control">
  <option>-select-</option>
  <option value="AA">Some AA Text</option>
  <option value="BB">Some BB Text</option>
  <option value="CC">Some CC Text</option>
</select>
// Note that I also tried with @DropDownListFor(m => m.SiteAbbreviation)
```

In the above controller action, I'm overwriting the model property SiteAbbreviation to be "AA" - so this should always be the selected option; however, when calling the action like so: Test?id=0&siteAbbreviation=BB, "BB" becomes the selected option. Using breakpoints, I can see that Model.SiteAbbreviation is properly being overwritten when it gets to the view.

I managed to fix this by changing the controller action's argument name from `string siteAbbreviation` to `string site`. This implies that the argument being the same as my model property threw the selected value of my tag helper off.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding data in client side,it will get value from ModelState prior to Model .You can try to add `ModelState.Clear` into the action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test(int? id = null, string siteAbbreviation = null)
{
    MyModel model = await GetModelData(id, siteAbbreviation);
    ModelState.Clear();
    model.SiteAbbreviation = "AA";

    return PartialView("Test", model);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Seems unintuitive when I'm telling the control to bind itself to my model property; because of this I'm going to stick with avoiding argument names that are the same as properties.